# Calling UIAlertView in block displays view multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, objective-c-blocks

I have a block completion being called from within a button press message and, depending on state, optionally a `UIAlertView` being displayed. However, when invoked the `UIAlertView` appears three (3) times...

1. With the full information but it disappears itself and shows
2. Just the title shows and when I click OK
3. Appears again with full information (as in #1) for which I have to dismiss again

Following is a snippet of the code:

```
        [credential performDataOperation:[credential commandForCreateOnClass:self.className]
                       withArguments:edits
                     completionBlock:^(BOOL succeded, id before, id after, NSDictionary *arguments, NSError *error) {
                         if (succeded) {
                             self.object = after;
                             self.objectWasCreated = YES;
                             [self prepareEditsDictionary];
                             self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled=NO;
                         }
                         else {
                             errorRecieved = YES;
                             [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Error Message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];

                         }
                     }];
```

Comment: You should show the code of your `performDataOperation:` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably seeing just two alerts. The first appears, but you also have code somewhere that summons the second, so it overrides the first. Then you dismiss the second and the first returns. You need to hunt for your code that presents the second alert, the one without the message, and figure out why that code is running. Just do a global search in your project for `UIAlertView`! It must be in there somewhere, because all alert views are created and presented in code.

You may have accidentally hooked up your button so that it has multiple action handlers. Of course I could be wrong, but this is a mistake I've sometimes made, and then I've been mystified why my method was being called twice or some unwanted extra thing was happening when I tapped the button. Check your nib/storyboard or code to make sure. The fact that a single button can have many actions for a single UIControlEvent is very surprising and is almost never used intentionally.

(If that's not the right answer, then perhaps the solution lies in your `performDataOperation` method, whose code you do not show. Maybe *it* calls the simpler UIAlertView, in addition to calling the block.)

Comment: The performDataOperation is a non-UI Core Data wrapper. There are other UIAlertViews in the code, setting breakpoints on each yields nothing. The only one being called in this use case is the one I showed. The button that invokes the performDataOperation is a button I added to the Navigation Bar so it just has one action handler. I am in the context of that one action.

Comment: Matt - I marked your answer +1 for putting me on the scent. It was the back-end that fell through a condition and checked for the block existence again and called it. Kudos...

Comment: I'm not impressed; I've made *that* kind of mistake too! :)